# How to make my desktop empty

Tags: 13.04, desktop-environments

How to make my desktop empty, that means when I login I need my desktop blank. I doesn't need any launchers and top indicator panel, I need empty screen(black) only. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Are you able to further clarify? Do you want to log into a console, or do you just want a really clean desktop environment?

Comment: i just want to clear desktop, when any file exists..

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand what reasons do you have to do this, but let's do it.

First move any files that you have in `~/Desktop` wherever else do you want using the following command from terminal:

```
mv ~/Desktop/* /path/to/another/directory
```

Second, make your desktop background black:

[image: appearance]

Third, run the [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] package and disable the **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**:

[image: ccsm]

[image: ccsm - unity plugin]

Related:

- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)